# Modularizar WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, organização-de-projeto

Tenho o seguinte cenário,

1 Sistema

Contendo diversas funcionalidades, dessas funcionalidades, tem algumas que são parecidas (Mudanças de Acordo com o Perfil do Usuário).

Só que estou com dificuldade para organizar isso no projeto.

Estou Criando um Sistema base, para chamar cada tela diferente.
Exemplo:

Sistema1=> CadCli1

Sistema2=>CadCli2

O que eu queria fazer, eliminar esses "Sistemas".

Fazendo da seguinte maneira

Sistema=> Se perfil 1 ChamaTela CadCli1
          Senão se Perfil2 ChamaTela CadCli2

Só que como faria isso? se no menu já especifico o form a Ser Instanciado?

```
CadCli1 cadCli= New CadCli1()
CadCli1.Show();
```

Tenho diversas telas então acho que não seria viável ficar fazendo if no código de abertura de cada tela.

Provavelmente estou organizando a estrutura do sistema de maneira errônea.

[upd]
Encontrei uma maneira de instanciar o form através de Reflection.

```
  Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("clMod1");
  Type t = assembly.GetType("clMod1.frmCadCli");
  Form frmCadCli= (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  frmCadCli.ShowDialog();
```

Dai dinamicamente carregaria os módulos ("clMod1") atraves do Perfil (configurado em uma tabela), Será que seria essa a solução?

Comment: Criar uma tela para cada cadastro, dependendo da quantidade (telas), diferença de layout, tamanho do projeto chega a ser inviável. A diferença entre um cadastro e outro é realmente grande? Tem algum esboço (telas) para mostrar?

Comment: Infelizmente tenho bastante telas com essas variações, a diferença de layout  na maioria dos casos é minima, ou eu tenho campos a mais, ou alguma ação a mais e feita caso seja de tal perfil. Outra coisa que preciso fazer devido aos requisitos, é habilitar algumas telas e desabilitar outras conforme o perfil. Tá bem complicada a estrutura do projeto.

Comment: a maneira com o reflection daria certo sim, mas acredito que seja arriscado, já que você já tem o perfil na tabela, poderia fazer um enumerador dos perfis, depois um switch case com o perfil que vem do banco, e então instanciar e mostrar o formulário conforme o perfil.

Comment: @ThiagoFalcão to pensando nisso mesmo, o que você acha que seria arriscado? o Controle da tabela? a Manutenção da Mesma?

Comment: @AndrewAlex acredito que o modo como vai instanciar a partir do módulo esteja incorreto, acredito que o correto seria a partir do perfil diretamente, no meu entendimento o que vai definir a visualização do módulo é o perfil, portanto o switch case no Perfil vindo do banco acho que seria o mais apropriado.

Comment: Usar reflection em grande quantidade pode ser realmente arriscado, é bem mais custoso computacionalmente falando do que instanciar diretamente as classes. Já pensou em herança?